# Gesture recogniser on UILabel, not working

Tags: ios, uilabel, uigesturerecognizer

I am trying to apply `UITapGestureRecognizer` on a `UILabel` in order to check and open e-mail service. The current `UIView` is a part of a `UIViewController` and displayed once user tap on a button.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>

@class AddressBook;

@interface ContactInfoUI : UIView <MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>{

    IBOutlet UIView *view;
    UIViewController *mContainerVc;
    AddressBook *mAddressBook;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain)UIView *view;
@property (nonatomic, retain)UIViewController *mContainerVc;
@property (nonatomic, retain)AddressBook *mAddressBook;

-(void)addContactInformationFrom:(AddressBook *)addressBook;

@end
```

.m

```
@implementation ContactInfoUI

@synthesize view;
@synthesize mContainerVc;
@synthesize mAddressBook;

- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ContactInfoView" owner:self options:nil];
        self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        [self addSubview:[self view]];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)addContactInformationFrom:(AddressBook *)addressBook{

    self.mAddressBook = addressBook;
    int y = 20;
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(20, y, 320, 60);

    if (![mAddressBook.aEmail isEqualToString:@"-"]) {
        UILabel *email = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:rect];

        UITapGestureRecognizer *tgr = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(showEmailForm:)];
        tgr.delegate = self;
        tgr.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
        [email addGestureRecognizer:tgr];
        email.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

        email.text = mAddressBook.aEmail;
        [self addSubview:email];
        rect.origin.y += 40;
    }
}

-(IBAction)showEmailForm:(id)sender{

    // Email Subject
    NSString *emailTitle = @"Test Email";
    // Email Content
    NSString *messageBody = @"Some message";
    // To address
    NSArray *toRecipents = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"test@apple.com"];

    MFMailComposeViewController *mc = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    mc.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    [mc setSubject:emailTitle];
    [mc setMessageBody:messageBody isHTML:NO];
    [mc setToRecipients:toRecipents];

    [mContainerVc presentViewController:mc animated:YES completion:NULL];
}

@end
```

VC.h (part)

```
@class ContactInfoUI;
@class ElementObject;

@interface ElementDetailsViewController : UIViewController{

    ElementObject *element;
    IBOutlet ContactInfoUI *infoView;
}

@property(nonatomic, retain) ContactInfoUI *infoView;

- (IBAction)showInfo:(id)sender;

@end
```

VC.m (part)

```
- (IBAction)showInfo:(id)sender {

    if (infoView == nil) {
        infoView  = [[ContactInfoUI alloc] init];
        infoView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        infoView.mContainerVc = self;
    }


    AddressBook *ab = element.getElementAddressBook;

    [infoView addContactInformationFrom:ab];
    [self.view addSubview:infoView];

    infoBtn.selected = YES;
    sumBtn.selected = NO;
    mapBtn.selected = NO;

    infoView.hidden = NO;
    staticMapScrView.hidden = YES;
    summaryView.hidden = YES;

}
```

The problem is that, even if I can see the actual `UILabel` on screen, I can't tap on it and the email function never fired.

Comment: Are you sure your label is smaller than its super views?

Comment: Hello there. Even without straight answer, your question really help. You were right, the actual `UIView` got `width=0` and that because, I forgot to connect the .xib file. Feel so bad for that silly mistake. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm glad you figured it.  Yeah, if a UI element is smaller than any of the its superviews (all the way up the chain), all UI interaction to that element will be blocked.  This goes for labels, buttons, etc..